# how to make less -S not take up the entire screen

Tags: terminal, less

suppose I have this: `cat new_file.txt | less -FRSX`

Then suppose I press the right button in order to scroll to the right

This will cause the contents of new_file.txt to move to the top of the command line and moreover there's a whole bunch of empty space between content of new_file.txt and the current command

For instance here's what it'll look like

```
contentsofnewfile.txtyupmorecontenntsconteeentsss
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
.
.
.
~
(END)
```

how do I make it so that even if I press the right button, the content of the file stays where it is instead of moving to the top (though it should still scroll to the right) and moreover that there will be no empty lines such as the

```
~
~
~
```

displayed above

Comment: It doesn't here... -FX should stop that.

Comment: be sure to include -S ... the point is to allow right scrolling ... without -S it's pointless

Comment: Ah, I see what you're talking about. It happens when a line is longer the than terminal width & you press right.

Comment: I suspect that the answer is “download the code source, write the code for that feature, recompile”.

Answer (score 1):

(I can't believe I am only the 2nd person in 8 years to have this same problem, in the world, and the history of Unix/Linux usage)

**Analysis**

- Does `less` have something like `more -c`? Yes `-c` functionality there.
- Does `less` have something like `more -20`? Yes `-z 20`, but its broken (see quote below).
- Does `less --window=-5` work? Yes, but not as expected, its broken (see quote below).
- Does `LINES=5 less --window=5` work as expected? No, its broken (see quote below).
- Does `less -c -5` function like `more -c -5`? Only when there is (in this case) 5 or less lines, ***and*** no keys are pressed.
- Does `less -F` do what you want (OP) is there is enough character space on screen? Yes.

`-5` `-z5` `-z 5` `--window=5` are all functionally equivalent.

If `-z` does *not* work like the manuals says:

> The `z` may be omitted for compatibility with some versions of more.

... then what *does* it do?

**Conclusion**

`--window=` currently *only* sets a *base* scroll-forward / scroll-back *PAGE size* (the base for `--max-forw-scroll` and `--max-back-scroll`), *not the view window size*.

Why does it function that way? Well, when `-z` was first added (its still in the `README` as a feature), it probably *did work* exactly like "some versions of more". But around the same time they introduced the code mentioned in the next quote, which broke `-z`, and for some reason everybody thought this was a good thing (because it was never fixed, or even flagged).

There is a piece in the (lengthy) manual page *right near the bottom*.

> Environment Variables
>
> `COLUMNS`
>
> Sets the number of columns on the screen. Takes precedence over the number of columns specified by the `TERM` variable. (But if you have a windowing system which supports `TIOCGWINSZ` or `WIOCGETD`, the window system's idea of the screen size takes precedence over the `LINES` and `COLUMNS` environment variables.)

`LINES` is the variable in question, that is affecting the OP (and me).

What is the expected functionality of `less -5` compared to `more -5`? It should be function identically, as the section (`Compatibility With More`) in the manual implies, you can use `less` as `more` (and I have used systems that do this).

> if the program is invoked via a file link named "more", less behaves (mostly) in conformance with the POSIX more command specification.

I'll bet that POSIX specification disputes current `-z` implementation.

*I* expect it worked once, because the Less enhancement was to provide a *negative* value, which works based on the *bottom* of the screen.

I think this is where it got screwed up, with not enough testing and use cases at the time, and the person who implemented it was not the same one implementing the new "dynamic window values".

I have the latest sources unpacked and I'll have a look at them tomorrow.

Comment: Are there any updates?

Answer (score -1):

Do a `cat new_file.txt | less -FRSXc`. That fixes the first issue.

For the second issue use a tilde `cat new_file.txt | less -FRSXc~`

**From the man pages for less:**

-c or --clear-screen
              Causes  full  screen  repaints  to  be  painted from the top line down.  By default, full screen repaints are done by scrolling from the bottom of the screen.

-~ or --tilde
              Normally lines after end of file are displayed as a single tilde (~).  This option causes
              lines after end of file to be displayed as blank lines.

Comment: so if I do that there's still a huge space between the end of file and the current command...is there a way to remove that space altogether (ie don't even display blank lines - just have the end of file be right above the current command)

Comment: No. Less is a program that runs in the shell. It's not actually stdout. That's why you have to end the program when it's done.